# Passing types as values in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to pass interfaces as values to a config object:

```
export interface RouterConfig {
  startEvents?: typeof RouterEvent[];
  completeEvents?: typeof RouterEvent[];
}
```

Usage should be like:

```
private config: RouterConfig = {
  startEvents: [NavigationStart],
  completeEvents: [NavigationEnd, NavigationCancel, NavigationError]
};
```

But it is throwing an error:

> Types of property 'completeEvents' are incompatible. Type '(typeof NavigationEnd | typeof NavigationCancel | typeof NavigationError)[]' is not assignable to type 'RouterEvent[]'. Type 'typeof NavigationEnd | typeof NavigationCancel | typeof NavigationError' is not assignable to type 'RouterEvent'. Type 'typeof NavigationEnd' is not assignable to type 'RouterEvent'. Property 'id' is missing in type 'typeof NavigationEnd'.

How can I fix it?

Here is a [stackblitz reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8vnfv)

Note that [RouterEvent](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent) is a class

Comment: I unmarked the question as duplicated, don't worry. I believe the root cause was the same, though - the `typeof` a child class is not always compatible with the `typeof` of it's parent class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classes all `NavigationEnd`, `NavigationCancel`, `NavigationError` have constructors with arguments. The type `RouterEvent` has a constructor without arguments. This is why the assignment fails. If you want to take in a constructor with any number of arguments you need to use a constructor signature that reflects that, for example this would work `new (...args: any[]) => RouterEvent` Angular already defines a type alias for this contructor in the form of the `Type` type. So we can write it like this:

```
import { Component, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterEvent, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationCancel, NavigationError } from '@angular/router';

export interface RouterConfig {
  startEvents?: Type<RouterEvent>[];
  completeEvents?: Type<RouterEvent>[];
}
let config: RouterConfig = {
  startEvents: [NavigationStart],
  completeEvents: [NavigationEnd, NavigationCancel, NavigationError]
};
```